# Can't switch from release to debug configuration in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I downloaded an ASP.NET open source solution and opened it in Visual Studio 2010. VS is running as admin.

Everytime I switch the solution or a project from Active (Release) to Debug and uncheck 'Optimize code' and save, these changes don't stick. The solution or project reverts back to Active (Release).

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I opened the csproj file in a text editor. Noticed there were two PropertyGroup sections which look like duplicates, one was Debug|AnyCPU and the second was Release|AnyCPU. I deleted the second one and the debug one showed up.

Comment: As written, this appears to be extremely bad advice. Unless you clarify the "look like duplicates" part, I'm going to downvote this.

Comment: This is an update. Removed the Release section, saved it. VS reloaded the file. Put the section back. Now I get a persisted debug configuration. I don't know why it works but it does.

Comment: This is the answer which worked for me and there are no side effects as the change is reverted.

Comment: I found that, when I added a custom build configuration, visual studio added the SAME build config MULTIPLE times in the csproj file. This caused me not being able to select this build config in the config manager. When I removed on of the duplicates, it did work.

Answer (score 46):

You also have to change it in Configuration-Manager (see pictures).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 14):

I just had this exact issue.  The solution ended up being:

Go to **Tools** ⇒ **Options** ⇒ Make sure **"Show All Settings"** in the lower left is checked.

Then, in that same window, go to **Projects and Solutions** ⇒ **General** ⇒ check **"Show advanced build configurations"**.

---

I have no idea why this checkbox was suddenly unchecked for me this morning, but this worked.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

*This is guessing a little, but anyways:*

Most likely, you are using build configurations that don't include your start up project for Debug build.

Look for the 'Manage Build Configurations' (I think, no Windows machine nearby) menu item. It will show you a list of projects with tickboxes on the right to show whether it is to be built in the build configuration.

Switch to 'Debug' in that dialog and make sure your startup project - *or the project that your starting the build for* - is actually included in the build.

**PS** It is even entirely possible that the 'misbehaving' project is actually lacking a Debug build (it might have a deviant name, like DebugConsole or something else entirely). In that case, use the Project menu to *add* a build configuration of the proper name for *that single project*. Afterwards, check (again) that said build configurations are checked in the 'solution wide' build configuration dialog.

HTH

Comment: All the projects were 'misbehaving'. I found a solution. Answer is posted.

Comment: I had this same issue, but the *configuration manager* option was hidden from all menus :| solution posted below..

Answer (score 3):

Changing the properties of a configuration doesn't change the current build configuration. If you open project properties, change from Release to Debug and make some changes, after exiting the dialog, you will build on the same platform as before. To change the platform you're building on, there is a combo-box right above the code - use that. You should have all available configurations in the list. When you open the project preferences dialog, the current configuration will be the default one in the dialog.

Comment: Great - A shortcut to the configuration manager's configurations that I just wasn't seeing before.

Answer (score 0):

Luchian Grigore's answer explains correctly one simple misconception that could lead to this problem and aaaaaaa's answer gives another way of correcting it: there is a dialog that looks like you are selecting the configuration to build but you are actually just selecting the configuration to *configure*.

However neither of their ways of opening the 'Configuration Manager' actually worked for me -- I had to click on the button configuration manager at the top right of the solution Properties.

(Note that the place where you *choose* the configuration is called Configuration Manager, whereas the place where you *manage* the configurations is Properties.)